# Issues with negative sign in front of rules for Logarithm simplification

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions

I declare a very simple rule.

```
rule = -x_*Log[a_] :> x*Log[1/a]
```

Now I give two expressions,

```
-x Log[d] /. rule
```

which gives me $x\log(1/d)$ but now if I give

```
-2 Log[d]/. rule
```

doesn't give me anything. Same problems for rules don't occur for +ve sign, for instance

```
rule = x_*Log[a_] + x_*Log[b_]:> x Log[a*b]
```

works well for constants and functions. Somehow "-" sign is causing problems. Any ideas ?

Comment: Look at the `FullForm` of your `rule` and various expressions.

Comment: I did, fullform of the rule is Rule[Times[-1,Log[Pattern[a,Blank[]]],Pattern[x,Blank[]]],Times[x,Log[Power[a,-1]]]] but -2Log[d] is Times[-2,Log[d]]. So is there way to pull out -2 and make it -1 to match the pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it is best to keep the left hand side of your rules as simple as possible, so I might write

```
rule = x_ Log[a_] -> Abs[x] Log[a^Sign[x]]
```

You need to be careful that your rules are valid for all the values that your variables could take.  We can use `Assuming` to enforce this

```
Assuming[x > 0, -x Log[d] /. rule // Refine]
(* x Log[1/d] *)
```

As desired

```
-2 Log[d] /. rule
(* 2 Log[1/d] *)
```

We might create more complex rules by applying conditions on the right hand side.  For example:

```
rule2 = u1_*Log[v_] + u2_*Log[w_] :> u2*Log[w/v] /; u1 == -u2;
```